# python array translate numpy referencing to non numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to find how to scan a block of 4 in any row of an array used to play connect4 with an AI, for which I'm trying to define moves priority.

Example: I have the following array/board:

```
board = [["." for i in range(7)] for i in range(6)]
board[0][3] = 'R'
board[0][2] = 'R'
board[0][1] = 'R'

[['.', 'R', 'R', 'R', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

I want to identify the pattern RRR and make my AI win the game by inserting another R next to it.
To do so, I'm trying to allocate a score to each column of the matrix.
To that end, I need to scan the array.

The code I'm trying to come up with serves that purpose.
Here's what I have so far

```
def position_score(board, piece):
    # horitontal scan
    for r in range(len(board)):
        row_ar = board[r]
        for c in range(len(board[0]) - 3):
            scan = row_ar[c: c + 4]
            if scan.count(piece) == 3 and scan.count(".") == 1:
                score += 10
```

Edit : figured out the print of the scan wasn't properly intended. newbie mistake, the solution brought by @hpaulj did work ! Thanks

Cheers

Comment: The first bit is not very numpy, and not valid python code. Please post an MCVE.

Comment: The more I look at this, the less sense it makes. Please clarify.

Comment: This is based on https://github.com/KeithGalli/Connect4-Python/blob/master/connect4_with_ai.py
Line 95
I'm trying to scan the rows of my board(array) to see where there are lines of 2/3 pieces, so that the AI plays there.
He is using numpy, I am not, and I'm trying to find the equivalent of this code.

Comment: `row_arr=array[r]` should be enough, if `array` is a list of lists.

Comment: @hpaulj. The conversion to `int` and a couple of other things make an MCVE necessary. A lot of code smell in that one snippet.

Comment: @Senzu. The author appears to be using numpy arrays as fancy nested lists. I can't comment on the algorithm itself, but certainly don't use that code as an example of how to efficiently use numpy

Comment: @MadPhysicist Updated the original post for clarity. The goal here is in fact not to use numpy, but I thought I could easily transpose from a numpy form to a regular form.

Comment: Thanks for the update. That helps a lot

Comment: That being said: your first snippet is not indented properly, and it's unclear what the problem with the second one is.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Updated with more details. Hope this is starting to make sense ^^"

Comment: Clear enough to post an answer. Why do you not want to use numpy?

Comment: @hpaulj ty for your suggestion btw, I updated my post with it, but it doesn't seem to scan properly yet

Comment: @MadPhysicist Simply because I'm not allowed to. I need to learn the raw/hard way, I suppose